# Invalid Update when re-ordering rows across sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to update my model when reordering some `UITableViewCells` across sections but getting the error:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 1 moved out).

I have the following code, where I thought I was deleting and inserting rows correctly?? (but obviously not ;-) )

```
    // Update the data model according to edit actions delete or insert.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let fromIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: indexPath.section)

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete{
        playingList.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row);
    }
}

    // Process the row move. This means updating the data model to correct the item indices.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let moveFrom = NSIndexPath(forRow: sourceIndexPath.row, inSection: sourceIndexPath.section)
    let moveTo = NSIndexPath(forRow: destinationIndexPath.row, inSection: destinationIndexPath.section)

    // swap the data between the 2 arrays
    let dataPiece = playingList[moveFrom.section][moveFrom.row]
    playingList[moveTo.section].insert(dataPiece, atIndex: moveTo.row)
    playingList[moveFrom.section].removeAtIndex(moveFrom.row)
    // Do the move between the table view rows
    playerTableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(moveFrom, toIndexPath: moveTo)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are calling `moveRowAtIndexPath`. Just update your data model and you are done.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let moveFrom = NSIndexPath(forRow: sourceIndexPath.row, inSection: sourceIndexPath.section)
    let moveTo = NSIndexPath(forRow: destinationIndexPath.row, inSection: destinationIndexPath.section)

    // swap the data between the 2 arrays
    let dataPiece = playingList[moveFrom.section][moveFrom.row]
    playingList[moveTo.section].insert(dataPiece, atIndex: moveTo.row)
    playingList[moveFrom.section].removeAtIndex(moveFrom.row)
}
```

BTW - your `commitEditStyle` method is incorrect too. It is deleting the data for a whole section (but using the row instead of section). Just remove the one row:

```
playingList[indexPath.section].removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, if I could double up vote you I would! :-)

Comment: Up voting and accepting is like a double up vote. Glad to help.